# Counter in a random guessing game

Tags: c#

Trying to get a counter to add the number of guesses

tried to increase the try count but unsuccessful

```
triesInteger = 0;

            if (guessInteger < numberRandom.Next(0, 10))
            {

                answerLabel.Text = "You are too low";
                numTriesLabel.Text = "" + triesInteger;
                triesInteger ++;

            }
            if (guessInteger > numberRandom.Next(0, 10))
            {

                answerLabel.Text = "You are too high";
                numTriesLabel.Text = "" + triesInteger;
                triesInteger ++;

            }
            if (guessInteger == numberRandom.Next(0, 10))
            {

                answerLabel.Text = "Correct, Way to go!";
                numTriesLabel.Text = "" + triesInteger;
                triesInteger ++;
```

when the user tries a guess the numTriesLabel should calculate the number of tries it took to get the correct random number.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong output?

Comment: Your logic is a bit out here, you a generating a new random number for each if condition

Comment: Also if this is getting called from a button, you are zeroing the `triesInteger` every time

Comment: `numberRandom.Next(0, 10)` should be called only once before the `if` checks, you are generating new number each time.

Comment: Wrong output. When i click submit the counter displays 0. Submitting another guess may increase to 1 but it never truly adds the number of tries correctly

Comment: I think you probably should work out how to use the debugger a little, you would actually figure this out fairly quickly if you debugged this

Comment: Well those all make sense now. I thought it was calling for a new random each time but thought i might be crazy too. Sorry I am new to c#.

Comment: You might find [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019) useful.

Comment: Okay so i changed some code around. The program works as it should except for the try counter. I looked through the debugging but it isn't clear what I should do I guess.

Comment: If it isn't already, you need to make the `triesInteger` a class level field so that it persists between (what I assume are) button clicks and then remove the `=0` from the top of the method.  You also need to remove ALL the calls to random.Next from this method as well. You should calculate that value once, probably when your form loads. Otherwise the target number changes every time you click the button. (or three times with your current implementation)

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody. I figured it out. The counter was starting at 0. I just changed the value to 1 and it counts exactly like it should.

Comment: @Devin128 you are changing counter starts from  0 to 1 its ok. It does not work previously because you show counter value in the text before it increments. `triesInteger++;` statement is at the end of each `if block` it should be start of each `if block`.  check my answer.

Comment: Thank you Mangesh! did even think to change the order of the operation

Comment: @Devin128 Ok.! then you can mark as accept the answer (one of the below ) which is helpful to solve your question or you fill no answer is helpful then you can write your own answer.

Comment: Using all the information that everyone gave helped me solve this issue. All of the answers are good. Thank you again for this!

Answer (score 1):

If you to check in how many tries the user to guess the random number, then you need to fix the Random number and tries globally or outside the block when you start the game.
Example:

```
    int triesInteger = 0;
    int randomnum = new Random().Next(0, 10);
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int guessInteger;
        if (int.TryParse(textBoxcommanf.Text, out guessInteger))
        {
            if (guessInteger < randomnum)
            {
                triesInteger++;
                answerLabel.Text = "You are too low";
                numTriesLabel.Text = "" + triesInteger;


            }
            if (guessInteger > randomnum)
            {
                triesInteger++;
                answerLabel.Text = "You are too high";
                numTriesLabel.Text = "" + triesInteger;


            }
            if (guessInteger == randomnum)
            {
                triesInteger++;
                answerLabel.Text = "Correct, Way to go!";
                numTriesLabel.Text = "" + triesInteger;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            answerLabel.Text = "Number is invalid";
        }
    }
```

It creates one random number and then user start to guess the number, each tries it count increase if guess wrong it shows hint (high or low).

If you want to start again then you need to reset the value on some button click .and start again number guessing game.

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        triesInteger = 0;
        randomnum = new Random().Next(0, 10);
        answerLabel.Text = "";
        numTriesLabel.Text = "0";
    }
```

Comment: Better to use `int.TryParse` and report an invalid value than to use `Convert.ToInt32` which will throw

Answer (score 0):

notice that `numberRandom.Next()` Generates a new random number, therefore in each if statement you generate a new random number.

what is exactly is

> unsuccessful

?

Answer (score 0):

You generate a new random at each if condition.

```
triesInteger = 0;
int number = numberRandom.Next(0,10)
if (guessInteger < number)
        {

            answerLabel.Text = "You are too low";
            numTriesLabel.Text = "" + triesInteger;
            triesInteger ++;

        }
        if (guessInteger > number)
        {

            answerLabel.Text = "You are too high";
            numTriesLabel.Text = "" + triesInteger;
            triesInteger ++;

        }
        if (guessInteger == number)
        {

            answerLabel.Text = "Correct, Way to go!";
            numTriesLabel.Text = "" + triesInteger;
            triesInteger ++;
```

Comment: While this helps to point out an issue, it's still most likely wrong. Assuming this is in a button click, the random number will change every time it's called. It should be set once, at the start of the guessing game. Also note that this answer does not address the actual question which was regarding the `triesInteger`